# What's the best short-term investment plan?

Tags: investing, short-term

Say I have a small sum of money, which I have no use for for the following 6-12 months. I don't want to invest it in index funds, because these have a non-negligible risk of decreasing  in this time period, and I need the money available.

What investment plan is better suited for this purpose?

If it matters, I live in Israel.

Comment: Is it really an investment if it's shorter than a year?

Comment: @Scott - it's someplace to put the money other than cash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is, *almost none*.

Almost everything has a risk of decreasing; but given your short time horizon and presumably given that you want back your principal in full, plus a little bit, you have few choices.

(Some of the following may be Canadian specific terms, but hopefully they are generic enough to apply)

Savings accounts, money-market funds and the like should be available at any bank.  Interest won't pay you much right now, but the money should be safe (I presume Israel has some kind of deposit insurance for normal bank accounts?)

Slightly more risky would be a short-to-maturity bond or stripped bond coupon.  The entry amount of money for one of these may be more than you have on hand, or the setup fee for an investment account might be more than you want to bother with for a one-off investment.

Given that you seem to indicate that you *might* need access to the money during the time-frame in question, the bank-account option seems to be the only one really available.

Comment: Minor nitpick: Money market funds are not typically insured deposits.

Comment: Money Market FUNDS and Money Market ACCOUNTS are two different things.

Answer (score 5):

I would put this money to a high-interest savings account. It will not earn you too much, but it will save it from inflation.

Comment: currently, all high-interest online savings account are at 1%. Does that still protect against inflation?

Comment: @Ramin the 1% will not save you from anything, but check the date when this comment was made. it was 3 years ago :)

Answer (score 4):

CDs or money market funds. Zero-risk for the CD and ultra-low risk for the money market account; better return than most savings accounts.

Comment: CDs... yes.  However, money market funds are not insured deposits and during the market crisis some of them actually "broke the buck", e.g. http://www.bloomberg.com/apps/news?sid=aLwxHK3Ygc8s&pid=20601087 ... but it is a rare occurrence according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_market_fund#Breaking_the_buck

Comment: Updated language to clarify that the CDs are the zero-risk and the money-market funds are still-ultra-low-risk.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what's "CDs" and money market funds?

Comment: Well, I see now the link to wikipedia for money market, but CDs?

Comment: A CD is a Certificate of Deposit. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_of_deposit

Comment: For what it's worth, in Canada we don't call them CDs, we call them GICs, for "Guaranteed Investment Certificate".  Many names, same thing.

Comment: Money market funds won't really provide much more interest than a savings account these days.